# How to add a pie chart based on all (or some) features in a layer?

Tags: qgis, statistics

I have a vector layer in a QGIS project which has about 60 items with various attributes, including a check for if an item is complete.  I am trying to get a pie chart showing the percentage of the items that are complete.

I can find how to add pie charts for individual records in a layer, but not a pie chart based on statistics for all (or some) features in a layer.

Answer (score 1):

QGIS 2.6 (Brighton, released Nov '14), [introduced](http://www.northrivergeographic.com/archives/qgis-2-6-virtual-fields) the virtual field option in the field calculator.  It allows for live calculations in the attribute table. However, the virtual field is removed if the layer id removed, It does remain if the virtual field is saved along with the project.  Here you can create a calculation for whatever statistic you need (%complete, %not complete).

Use these columns with the diagram layer style and the pie charts will always update with there progress.

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen a way of doing exactly what you are looking for, but in the Vector -> Research menu you will find a "Basic Statistics" and "List Unique Values" tools that allow you to extract highlight information from a layer and then paste it into a programme that will do this (a spreadsheet programme for instance).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create your own map canvas item, calculating aggregate statistics and exposing them in a cusom widget.
You can refer to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69398/how-to-add-a-dynamic-timeline-to-the-qgis-canvas/69844#69844) for some how-to-get-started reference concerning the widget.