# Show a single value related to a whole layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I'm developing a maximum flow plugin for QGIS.  I would like to show a calculation result (i.e., the maximum flow) on the map.  The result is not a property of a single feature.  It is a property of a whole layer.  What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you please supply more information such as what is this 'calculation result', what code you have developed so far etc?

Comment: @Joseph  I revised my question.

Comment: @wannik it would help if you could share further information on where you're stuck, what you've tried, etc. At the moment the question is still very vague.

Comment: Where do you need to show the information? On the map canvas, a dock/dialog of your plugin or in a map composer?

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn I'd like to show a string on a map canvas (if possible).  A user can see it all the time no matter the position or zoom level.

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn thank you very much for the solution.

Comment: @wannik It would be nice if you could share your code for future readers. You can edit my answer and add a section there to have it all in one place or write an own answer if you prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you will need to do in python in order to solve this problem

## Calculating the values

There is no support for aggregate expressions in QGIS, so you will have to resort to implementing your own logic with python.

You can do the following:

- Use `QgsVectorLayer.maximumValue( fieldIndex )` if you just need the maximum value of a given field.
- Write your logic in python and connect it to the appropriate signals to be recalculated. `QgsVectorLayer.attributeValueChanged(fid, idx, value)` is a good candidate for you.

## Drawing on the map

You can refer to this previous answer about how to add a new item to the map canvas. Just adapt the paint method to print a string instead of the bar.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/69844/9839